# Storing image from camera in new folder android

Tags: android, camera, android-image, android-external-storage

I am creating an app where I want the user to pick which folder to save their images in. I first want to see if I could figure out how to save the images in another folder besides the default folder but I keep getting an error and can't figure out why.

Here is the code I have to start the camera intent and to get the file directory name

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_smart_wardrobe);
    camera = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cameraBtn);
    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            file = getOutputMediaFileUri();
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE );
        }
    });

}
```

Here is the code for the uriFileDirectory

```
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
}

 private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
   File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");

    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");


    return mediaFile;
}
```

Here is my onActivityResult method

```
@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                    data.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "There is someting wrong with your code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                images = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(images);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help fix my code?

Comment: Please post your `log cat`. Also have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ` permission in  your manifest.

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: I am getting this error

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity {ash.smartwardrobe/ash.smartwardrobe.SmartWardrobe}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference

Comment: I just added the permission in and I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first your permission in Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and `onActivityResult` method check that is it returning a file path or not. add the line in this method

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" +
                   file, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "There is someting wrong with your code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

the problem was in your toast. In Camera Intent we get intent as null and you are trying to taking data from there. you have to use Uri.

Comment: I added the permission and the extra line of code and still the same error

Comment: @Ashley are you there??

Comment: @Ashley I solved your problem just check  the updated code and accept and upvote it.